# Failing to execute MySQL dump on windows 10, IDE is Netbeans 8.2

Tags: java, mysql, windows, netbeans

I have been searching for hours on how to backup the schema for my database through Netbeans 8.2 I just want to backup my work in the event of computer failure. I tried using command line but no resource is up to date yet on how to properly backup for windows 10 and Netbeans 8.2. Any solution would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Any error prompted? what is it?

Comment: You can use MySQL browsers like [MySQL Workbench](https://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/) or [SQLyog Enterprise](https://www.webyog.com/) to take database backup or to restore db. Why are you wandering with Netbens to take backup of db? And for the command line check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13484728/5180017) StackOverflow thread.

Answer (score 1):

NetBeans does not offer this feature. You can only grab and recreate the structure of single tables (Under Services / Databases / [your database] / right click on any table). But this does not include any containing data.
Shashanth mentioned already some alternatives where I would like to add  [HeidiSQL](http://www.heidisql.com/) which does an awesome job.

If you want to implement this as a feature in your own application you probably want to call mysqldump from your program (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16076499/how-to-backup-and-restore-a-mysql-database-using-netbeans?rq=1) in addition to the [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13484728/5180017) provided by Shashanth)

Comment: I found the folder where it hard saved them and just copied them to a flash drive. Thank you all for the support though.